# Quicker conversion to WebP

Tags: image, converters, webp

I've tried [WebP converter](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) to convert images to WebP format, but it takes about 1-2 second for one image to convert. I have around 70 images and I'd like to convert them in less than a minute. Is there a quicker way how to do it?

Comment: You got any Solution

Answer (score 2):

'cwebp -lossless -q 0 -m 1' is used in https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/webp_lossless_alpha_study for fast lossless comperession. It averages at 19 ms per image for a web corpus of 1000 randomly sampled PNG-images.

How big are these images? What kind of computer do you use to convert? Do you have an alpha-channel in the images? Do you convert to lossless or lossy? Which version of cwebp are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Here is best site i have found for online image conversion it also compress the size for image and the interesting is that you can convert multiple image at a time
https://www.pixconvertify.com/png-to-webp

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34972300)